# Rails 5 assets not loading consistently in Production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `= javascript_include_tag "subfolder/Js_File"` at the end of the page in a view (HAML).

I have the following line in manifest application.js
`//= link_directory ./subfolder`

When I clear the browser cache and load the application for the first time. My assets are not loading (No CSS and JS). When I do a CTRL+R or Command+R. The page loads with CSS and JS.

But still the JS in "subfolder/Js_File" is not loaded. When I navigate out from this page and later navigate back to the page my "subfolder/Js_File" file loads and works as expected.

My production.rb has the following lines for assets

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true # tried changing this to false
  config.assets.compile = true # tried changing this to false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: assets -> javascripts -> subfolder -> Js_file.js is the assets directory structure. 
On the console I get 404 assets not found. But after a ctrl+r refresh everything works fine. This seems to be very wierd.

Comment: Also for the first time load, application.css is show 404 on the console

Comment: This sounds like the sprockets gremlin, try removing sprockets from your gemfile, and application.js, then remove the "data-turbolinks" from any of your include tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above configuration is correct. There was a problem with the remotely hosted asset server, it is load balanced. On one of the node the assets were not getting copied. Infrastructure had to be fixed.